# How do I get all Facebook friends birthdays on my windows live calendar?

Tags: sync, contacts, calendars, facebook

Currently I have configured Live, Yahoo, Gmail and Facebook accounts to my windows phone 7.5 (Device is Lumia 710).

The weird problem is, In calendar, Only birthdays from Live, Google Mail and Yahoo mail is visible.

But I have all my friend's birthday in facbook account.

Note: I have checked settings of Phone calendar for 100 times. And also, I have selected the option for making visible the Facebook events on Windows calendar.

Any Idea? what might be the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import them into your Live Calendar and then that will sync with your phone. To do that just do the following:

1. Go to the events page on FaceBook.
2. Scroll down to the bottom and look for where it says "Past Events · Birthdays · Export" and click on "Bithdays".
3. Scroll down to the bottom and look for where it says "Past Events · Export Birthdays" and click on "Export Bithdays".
4. Copy the URL on the bottom of the Pop Up.
5. Log into your live account and go to your Live Calendar and click on Subscribe.
6. Paste the URL in the "Calendar URL" box.
7. Enter Calendar name (Call it whatever you want e.g. "FaceBook Birthdays" or whatever).
8. Click on the "Subscribe to calendar" button.

Next time your phone syncs all your FaceBook birthdays should appear in your calendar.

Comment: Thanks...., It is just what I wanted..., Thanks Again. :)

Comment: No worries. I had to do this with Gmail on my old n900 years ago. It really should be easier.

Comment: Do I still have to do this for winphone 8?

Comment: I'm not using WP8 but I imagine so.

Answer (score 0):

Or you link your Live account with your facebook account and scare the crap outa yourself when u get windows 8 like close to a year later then wonder how it knows more about you than you do.

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer, how can you do this and what exactly will happen?